# Custom component FormControl breaking if reinitializing FormGroup from parent

Tags: angular, angular-components

I got a problem when reinitializing  formGroup from parent component that is used in my custom component. Error that i get is:

> There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with
> name: 'selectedCompany'

**HTML**:

```html
<form [formGroup]="addForm">
     ...
     <my-custom-component formControlName="selectedCompany"></my-custom-component>
     ...
</form
```

`<my-custom-component>` is created according to valid way of creating custom formControl component: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html#implementing-controlvalueaccessor

**Component**

This is code that initializes formGroup variable `addForm`:

```js
let formTemp: any = {
    selectedCompany: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
}

this.addForm = this._formBuilder.group(formTemp);
```

First time `addForm` is initialized all is good. But when i reopen modal where form is located, and same component code is executed, above mentioned error occurs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured out that it is not good to reinitialize `formGroup` over and over again, because component looses reference to old `formGroup`.

If setting values is what is needed to show fresh form, `.setValue` is the solution here:

**Component**

Instead of reinitializing `addForm`, check if `addForm` was initialized previously and if so, only set value for existing `FormControls`:

```js
if (this.addForm) {
    this.addForm.setValue({
        selectedCountry: null
    })
} else {

    let formTemp: any = {
        selectedCompany: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    }

    this.addForm = this._formBuilder.group(formTemp);
}
```

In this way, I figured, reference is not lost to old `addForm`, so no error occurs.

Comment: You can also use [FormGroup].patchvalue(object) if you only want to update a select number of properties/form controls

Comment: Mario, thank you so much for this solution, this is much better then @zucker's answer (btw offered by all others), also I believe this solution should be considered as a default form creation in general.

Answer (score 19):

My solution for that is to replace `formControlName` with `formControl`.

Instead of

```html
<my-custom-component formControlName="selectedCompany"></my-custom-component>
```

use

```html
<my-custom-component [formControl]="addForm.controls['selectedCompany']"></my-custom-component>
```

or with some getMethod for taking `formControl`

Works also with error:

> There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with
> path

where I've used some `FormArray`.

Comment: That's what worked for me with the new DateRange and Angular material. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found a weird "solution" to this. So to reset the subcomponents, which use the formGroup and get confused when you swap it out. I use this hack.

**comp.ts**

```js
public flicker: boolean = false;

reInit() {
    this.flicker = true;

    this.addForm = this._formBuilder.group({
         selectedCompany: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    });

    setTimeout( () => this.flicker = false, 200); //On very heavy pages, timeout ensures that the flicker hack works as expected.
}
```

comp.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="addForm" *ngIf="!flicker">
     ...
     <my-custom-component formControlName="selectedCompany"></my-custom-component>
     ...
</form>
```

Horrendeous hack, which basically enforces the formGroup components to destroy and re-initialize themselves, but desperate times call for desperate measures...

I needed this hack, because I use FormGroup objects to save the results of a form into an interim array of results, each of which can be re-opened and edited at will. In the future, I will be making ngModel based form state saving, to avoid this issue, but a temporary solution is here.

## Edit 1

```js
setTimeout(() => this.flicker = false, 200); //On very heavy pages, timeout ensures that the flicker hack works as expected.
```

There is a better way to synchronously do the flicker

```js
this.flicker = true;
this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
this.flicker = false;
this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

detect changes will synchronously run the change detection and update the view, thus removing the old `FormGroup`.

Comment: Yea, for your use case with reactive forms solution.